# SQL on three tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables

- `cl_address`: FK - cl_ser_id, FK - add_ser_id
- `address`: PK - add_ser_id
- `youths_info`: FK - cl_ser_id

I would like to

```
select * 
from youths_info

select * 
from address
```

Can some guru please help and with code and suggest the most optimized SQL?

Below is my trial code which is causing an error on the last `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT a.*, y.* 
FROM [informix.address] a  
INNER JOIN [informix.cl_address] cla ON a.addr_ser_id = cla.addr_ser_id
INNER JOIN [informix.cl_address] cla ON [youth_info] y
cla.cl_ser_id = y.cl_ser_id
```

Comment: Please be more clear with your question. This information is so scarce that no one will bat an eye to this. Refer [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, for your own good!

Answer (score 0):

As there is no sample data and desired result, I am assuming that you need query as below.

```
SELECT a.*,
       yi.*
FROM address a
JOIN cl_address cla ON a.add_ser_id = cla.add_ser_id
JOIN youths_info yi ON yi.cl_ser_id = cla.cl_ser_id;
```

The above query will return `inner` results of all columns from `address` and `youth_info` table. If you need `left` or `right` `outer` result, you have to adjust the joins in above query according to your `dbms`.